# NetBeans: Choosing variable type to place in comment

Tags: php, netbeans

I am wanting to utilize the variable type comment feature in NetBeans for PHP, yet I'm having trouble deciding upon the type itself.

I've got the syntax down (my variable is named `$clause`):

```
/* @var $clause type */
```

But when it comes to replacing `type` with something, I'm unsure of what to use. I used `gettype($clause)` to determine the type of variable in question, which outputted `string`, yet there is no `string` option in the drop down list for the autocompletion of the comment in NetBeans.

Furthermore the options that *are* listed are foreign to me to say the least, and I don't imagine a developer is expected to use `gettype` *every* time they need to determine the type of variable in use.

Could someone give me some advice on the type to use? Is it `string` as I determined, or is this a user defined type?

I noticed in the documentation [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/defining_variable_type_in_a) that the types given as examples are `Book` and `Movie`, which match the `class` name in the given examples. My case does not contain a `class`, but there is no example that resembles my case.

I appreciate any help you can provide me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm, I think you mean [PHPDoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc), no? It's not a Netbeans feature...

The data type doesn't really matter in the long run, it only helps you designing self-documented code.

Finally, if the `$clause` variable indeed contains a class name (most often a string), the DocBlock would look like:

```
/**
 * @var $clause string Some class name.
 */
```

Note that docblocks must start with a slash and *two* asterisks.

The @var clause is in the format of "variable name", "data type" and "description".

Comment: Ok, so you were right. It is PHPDoc. I'm still not sure of what I am suppose to place as the DocBlock class name. Is it defined in the code, or do I just make something up? Sorry for sounding so dumb; My brain is scrambled trying to figure this out.

Comment: Yes and no. In PHP, the keywords "string" "integer" etc are mainly used for typecasting. They can also be used in PHPDoc.